# how to patch values in nested map

Tags: java, dictionary, key, patch

I have 2 nested maps, i want to compare those 2 maps using the keys and replace the values
first map:

```
{
    "atBaseType": "abc",
    "atType": "abc",
    "id": "ot10",
    "name": "ot10",
    "version": "1.0",
    "validFor": {
        "endDateTime": "2023-02-25T00:00:00Z",
        "startDateTime": "2023-02-01T00:00:00Z"
    }
}
```

second map:

```
{
    "validFor": {
        "endDateTime": "2023-04-25T00:00:00Z",
    }
}
```

result map should be :

```
{
    "atBaseType": "abc",
    "atType": "abc",
    "id": "ot10",
    "name": "ot10",
    "version": "1.0",
    "validFor": {
        "endDateTime": "2023-04-25T00:00:00Z",
        "startDateTime": "2023-02-01T00:00:00Z"
    }
}
```

basically i want to patch new endDateTime from 2nd map to 1st map without changing any other values in 1st map.

if i use map.putall() or map.replaceAll(), the issue is it will append new value to endDateTime and append null to startDateTime..

```
{
    "atBaseType": "abc",
    "atType": "abc",
    "id": "ot10",
    "name": "ot10",
    "version": "1.0",
    "validFor": {
        "endDateTime": "2023-04-25T00:00:00Z",
        "startDateTime": null
    }
}
```

can anyone help me in this issue

Comment: please add the language tag. seems it's java

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera, its java